# How to distinguish between a new window and a new tab in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to know if there is any way to distinguish between a new window and a new tab, natively in Selenium.

On my test page there are buttons to open a page in the same window, a new window, or a new tab.

I know how to switch to the new window or tab using window handles, but I cannot distinguish between the two. How do I know if the button opened the link in a new tab, and not a new window?

i.e. in pseudocode (need code for `openedInNewWindow()` and `openedInNewTab()`)

```
click(newTabButton);
if (openedInSameWindow()) {
    Log.Error("Link opened in same window :(");
} else if (openedInNewWindow()) {
    Log.Error("Link opened in new window :(");
} else if (openedInNewTab()) {
    Log.Success("Link opened in new tab :)");
} else {
    Log.Error("Link didn't open anything :(");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet for new window,

```
 WebDriver newWindow = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.WINDOW);
    newWindow.get("https://blog.testproject.io/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Code snippet for new tab,

```
 WebDriver newTab = driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
    newTab.get("https://testproject.io/platform/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

-Arjun

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these code snippets are for making selenium open a new window or tab, then navigate to a url in that new window or tab.  I'm looking to determine if clicking a link opened a new window, or if it opened a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't find any way to do this. But if your new window has different dimensions than current window, it's easy to detect it.

```
// size of current active window
const originalSize = JSON.stringify(await driver.manage().window().getRect());

// open new window/tab and switch to new windowHandle
await driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);

// get size of new window
const size = await driver.executeScript(function () {
    return { x: window.screenX, y: window.screenY, height: window.innerHeight, width: window.innerWidth };
});
/** 
* now you can compare the size with originalSize
* If they're same - it's a new tab, otherwise new window
*/
```

But please keep in mind, this only works well if new window is supposed to be of different dimension.